# Вывод записей с ID рубрики каждой записи. WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

У меня есть таксономия по которой я вывожу записи:

```
    <?php
    global $post; 

    $args = array('numberposts' => -1, 'post_type' => 'catalog-object'); 

    foreach( $myposts as $post ){ setup_postdata($post); 

    $getcat = get_the_category(); ?>
<div class="category-<?php echo $cat->term_id; ?>"
 <!-- пытаюсь получить ID рубрики у каждой записи -->
      <?php the_title(); ?>
</div>
      <?php } wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Мне нужно выводить запись и рядом перечень id , в которой эта запись находится.

Чтобы на выходе был div с классами каждой категории (если не одна). Пример

```
    <div class="category-1 category-2">
Запись 1
    </div>
    <div class="category-3 category-4">
Запись 2
    </div>
```

Comment: `<?php echo $cat->term_id; ?>` - при чем здесь переменная $cat?

Comment: Видимо остаток кода моих эксперементов

Comment: $cat = get_the_category($post_id); использовал , но не помогло

Comment: Пробовали ли Вы пользоваться этой функцией? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_categories/

Comment: Не пробовал, сейчас попробую

Comment: <?php echo wp_get_post_categories( $post->ID, array('post_type' => 'catalog-object') ); ?> пытался так вывести - не работает

Comment: Там чуть ниже есть конкретный пример как в цикле получить категории.

Comment: Там цикл вывода категорий, не постов

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77672/discussion-between-daemonhk-and-).